# Get Affiliate ID from URL

Tags: affiliate

So I'm a newbie and I do know some HTML and PHP. Don't get too advanced on me though.

I have a page like this `mywebsite.com/?s1=affiliateid`

I want to take the `affiliateid` part out of the URL. Every affiliate will put a different username into the address.

Then I want to create a link will point to `differentwebsite.com/?id=affiliateid` based on the username typed into the address bar.

I know I have to define `s1` somewhere. I don't know how this works. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at adding a $_GET variable to the mywebsite.com/?s1=page.

Something like this will get that affiliate id

```
$aff_id = $_GET['s1'];
```

Then you can use that variable to create a link or just redirect it to the next page

```
differentwebsite.com/?id=$aff_id
```

In PHP it would look like this

```
echo '<a href='http://differentwebsite.com/?id='.$aff_id.'">Link to other site</a>';
```

make sense?

Comment: @BryanSpector - I see you tried to edit my post for your answer.  You need to click add comment and followup.